# PCA for model coefficients

Tags: regression, pca, regression-coefficients

I have a regression problem with strong multi-colinearity.  The question is about the effect of the variables more-so than the prediction from the model.  Is it valid to divide the coefficient of a principal component using the loadings from that principal component to find an approximate contribution of the variables making it up?  If so, is there a way to calculate a confidence interval on these approximations?  If not, any other suggestions?